# Why is there no "," in this map, but no error is prompted

Tags: flutter, hashmap

[image]

```
 Future<Result?> netFetch(
    String method,
    path, {
    Map<String, dynamic>? params = const {},
    ...
```

I saw this code in the project today, the editor did not report an error, and it can run normally, I don't know why

Comment: Try restarting your system & IDE & check if whether error is linted or not. If still problem persists, add comma manually or it can lead to bugs & crashes in production environment.